# Gathering Perfmon Counters with Powershell, any way to insert datetime instead of just time?

Tags: datetime, powershell

I have a Powershell script that gathers a series of Performance Counters and stores them in a log file for a SQL server.

Currently the output of this log includes the following column: `PDHCSV40EasternDaylightTime240`

This pushes out a MM:SS.ms into that column, but doesn't give the hour or date so that makes any counters gathered after an hour pretty worthless.

Is there any way to change the format of that column in the Powershell script? Ultimately, the logs are stored in .csv, which I then clean up and pump into SQL using a .bat file that calls LogParser 2.2, so it's possible that I could use a SQL script to create a datetime based on the RowNumber.

Here is the code that actually creates the log:

```
$Folder="C:\Perflogs\SQLLogs" # Change the bit in the quotation marks to whatever directory you want the log file stored in

$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$1GBInBytes = 1GB
$p = "TONS OF COUNTERS";

# If you want to change the performance counters, change the above list. However, these are the recommended counters for a SQL machine. 

$date = Get-Date -Format 'MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm_ss'
$file = "$Folder\SQL_log_$date.csv"

if( !(test-path $folder)) {New-Item $Folder -type directory}

Get-Counter -counter $p -SampleInterval 60 -Continuous | export-counter -Path $File -FileFormat CSV
```

Comment: Create a function to get the counter you want (not using -continous), append result to the log file with the current date time and run this every minutes?

Comment: What program are you using to view your CSV data? When I run your example with a few random performance counters and view the results in Sublime, the timestamp shows up as a full datetime.

Comment: I viewed the data with both Notepad++ and Excel, as well as looking at it in SQL once it'd be pushed into SQL. It's not returning as the datetime stamp, so there might be a difference in the server config or something.

@Kayasax, if I lose the -continuous that kind of makes the entire script worthless, as it's supposed to be a tool to monitor perfmon counters until it's turned off.

Comment: Ah-ha, I figured it out. A part of the process I was taking to load it into SQL stripped out the date portion of the date-time.

Answer (score 1):

I run the last line of the script and I got the date/month/year,etc. Do I miss something?

```
PS C:\Documents\ManualScripts> get-counter -counter "\processor(_total)\% processor time" -SampleInterval 5 -Continuous
| Export-Counter -path .\Test-files\counter -FileFormat csv
```

The content of the exported file:

```
PS C:\Documents\ManualScripts> get-content .\Test-files\counter
"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (Eastern Daylight Time)(240)","\\win2012-2\processor(_total)\% processor time"
"06/18/2013 14:48:00.742"," "
"06/18/2013 14:48:05.843","9.1628941466886715"
"06/18/2013 14:48:10.910","9.4105840748880283"
"06/18/2013 14:48:15.953","14.770849818884757"
"06/18/2013 14:48:20.993","12.40314193479044"
"06/18/2013 14:48:26.043","22.617568840081649"
"06/18/2013 14:48:31.086","21.901970809646333"
"06/18/2013 14:48:36.203","10.671110542619488"
"06/18/2013 14:48:41.243","17.654344180766689"
"06/18/2013 14:48:46.277","16.714921378494417"
"06/18/2013 14:48:51.318","10.501397411247293"
"06/18/2013 14:48:56.359","10.875155019759863"
```

Answer (score 0):

I determined that running the Powershell script without any interference from me after creating the .csv resulted in the format of datetime I wanted, so the problem is with how I'm cleaning up the .csv prior to loading it into SQL.